# Правильный SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

Необходимо вывести все данные с таблицы list, если значение поля login таблицы list **отсутствует** во второй таблице newlist.

```
SELECT * FROM list as b, newlist as a WHERE b.login != a.login
```

Не работает должным образом

Comment: Другими ловами вывести все записи из list, для которых в newlist нет записей с таким же значением login

Comment: Да, вы верно поняли.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT b.* 
  FROM list as b
  LEFT JOIN newlist as a ON b.login = a.login 
 WHERE a.login is null
```

Comment: к сожалению, не удалось запустить, ошибка

Comment: `on` в нужное место переставь